# Trash and mounted volumes in Ubuntu Dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, trash, ubuntu-dock

When you install Ubuntu 18.04, you won't have Trash in the Dock (Launcher). Instead, it's in the Desktop, and when you mount a volume, it appears in the Desktop; And it's a little messy if you have another stuff on your Desktop.

So I downloaded tweak-tool, there's an option to remove the trash icon and mounted volumes from Desktop.

How can I set the trash and mounted volumes to appear on the Dock just like previous versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you actually using Unity here, or the default GNOME Shell?

Comment: @muru Sorry, by Dash i meant launcher. corrected. And i just installed Ubuntu 18.04. So it would be its default shell i guess.

Comment: A not-so-elegant workaround for trash icon: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067164/remove-trash-icon-from-desktop-and-add-to-ubuntu-dock-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in terminal for enabling 'Trash' icon on dock

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash true
```

To disable the same, execute

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash false
```

Comment: Still works in Ubuntu 21.10.