# Remove trash icon from GNOME desktop and add to Ubuntu dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, trash, ubuntu-dock

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and don't like having the trash icon on the desktop rather that in the launcher (Ubuntu dock).

How can I move it back to the launcher? Can other icons be moved from the desktop to the launcher?

Answer (score 16):

### Removing the Trash icon from desktop

#### Up to Ubuntu 18.10

Launch Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false
```

You may alternatively use GUI tools like *dconf-Editor* or *(GNOME) Tweaks* (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965881/how-to-remove-trash-icon-from-gnome-desktop) for reference).

#### Ubuntu 19.04 and later

Disable the trash icon option from *Extensions* > *Desktop Icon* in Tweaks:
[image]
Alternatively, run the following command (note that this does not work from 21.04 onwards)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false
```

---

### Adding a Trash icon to the Ubuntu dock

#### Up to Ubuntu 19.04

Follow the steps below.

1. First install the `trash-cli` package by running

   ```
   sudo apt install trash-cli
   ```
2. Create a `.desktop` file (say `trash-in-dock.desktop`) in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.
3. Open the file with a text editor and add the following lines

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Trash icon for Ubuntu dock
   Terminal=false
   Name=Trash for Dock
   Exec=nautilus trash:///
   Type=Application
   Icon=user-trash
   NoDisplay=false
   Actions=empty-trash;

   [Desktop Action empty-trash]
   Name=Empty Trash
   Exec=trash-empty
   ```
4. Save the file and re-login if needed.
5. Click "*Activities*" or press <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for *Trash for Dock*. It should appear in the results.
6. Right click the icon and select "*Add to Favourites*".

**What you will get**

1. A Trash icon in your dock, clicking which will open the Trash folder.
2. Right clicking the Trash icon in the dock will show an "*Empty Trash*" option which should work as intended.
   [image]

**What you won't get**

1. The Trash icon in the dock would be like other app icons, it won't be conveniently placed at the bottom like in Unity Launcher.
2. The Trash icon in the dock would be a 'static' one, i.e. won't show two different icons depending on whether the Trash is empty or not.

#### Ubuntu 19.10 and later

Simply run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash true
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will give it a try. I don't know why they took it out of the launcher/dock to begin with or why the nomenclature has to be changed just to confuse things.

Comment: @user607003 It's not just the nomenclature, it goes deeper than that. Ubuntu 18.04 uses GNOME instead of Unity (after 6 years or so). The changeover is massive.

Comment: About the step _Save the file and re-login if needed._: Is not necessary, not even to reset (alt+f2 r).

Comment: @pablo Are you *absolutely* sure that's not required? I, *for one*, a few times experienced the issue of a newly created custom launcher not appearing in 'Show Applications' immediately after creation (and at least restarting GNOME shell was required).

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can be _absolutely sure_ about something. I just did it and it wasn't necessary. Gnome 3.28.3 @ 18.04.2. Maybe you could leave  it at the end as a note if it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand the desktop file thing how do i type it?

Comment: @AdnanHossain As stated in step 3, **open with a text editor**.

Comment: i get this error ```No such schema “org.gnome.nautilus.desktop”```

Comment: @gccallie Are you sure you are using Ubuntu **18.04**?

Comment: @pomsky my mistake, I am on ubuntu 20.04. I solved by going  to the extension management page (https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) then opening dash to dock configuration. Inside "Launchers" panel I found the "Show trash can" toggle option.

Comment: Yes, this (question and) answer is not very useful for newer releases as they come with a trash on the dock feature by default.

Comment: On Fedora 37 with Gnome 43, the setting is in "Extensions -> Dash to Dock -> Launchers -> 5th switch says "Show trash can". `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock` says not found